# How to solve equations with complex coefficients using ode45 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I am trying to solve two equations with complex coefficients using ode45.
But iam getting an error message as "Inputs must be floats, namely single or
double."

```
X = sym(['[',sprintf('X(%d) ',1:2),']']);

Eqns=[-(X(1)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632 + (X(2)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632; (X(2)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632 + X(1)*(- 2500000 + (5223289665997855453060886952725538686654593059791*1i)/324518553658426726783156020576256)] ;

f=@(t,X)[Eqns];

[t,Xabc]=ode45(f,[0 300*10^-6],[0 1])
```

How can i fix this ? Can somebody can help me ?

Comment: Hmmm... Can you separate your diff Eq. into real and imaginary parts and use ode45 on each separately?

Comment: @anon0909 I do not think that the problem is in complex numbers, ode45 should easily handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the  [MathWorks Support Team](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102582#answer_111927), the "ODE solvers in MATLAB 5 (R12) and later releases properly handle complex valued systems."  So the complex numbers are the not the issue.

The error "Inputs must be floats, namely single or double." stems from your definition of `f` using Symbolic Variables that are, unlike complex numbers, not floats.  The easiest way to get around this is to not use the Symbolic Toolbox at all; just makes `Eqns` an anonymous function:

```
Eqns= @(t,X) [-(X(1)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632 + (X(2)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632; (X(2)*23788605396486326904946699391889*1i)/38685626227668133590597632 + X(1)*(- 2500000 + (5223289665997855453060886952725538686654593059791*1i)/324518553658426726783156020576256)] ;

[t,Xabc]=ode45(Eqns,[0 300*10^-6],[0 1]);
```

---

That being said, I'd like to point out that numerically time integrating this system over 300 microseconds (I assume without units given) will take a long time since your coefficient matrix has imaginary eigenvalues on the order of `10E+10`.  The extremely short wavelength of those oscillations will more than likely be resolved by Matlab's adaptive methods, and that will take a while to solve for a time span just a few orders greater than the wavelength.

I'd, therefore, suggest an analytical approach to this problem; unless it is a stepping stone another problem that is non-analytically solvable.

---

Systems of ordinary differential equations of the form

[image: Equation for a linear, homogenous, constant coefficient system of ordinary differential equations],

which is a linear, homogenous system with a constant coefficient matrix, has the general solution

[image: General matrix exponential solution to the system of ODEs],

where the *m*-subscripted exponential function is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).
Therefore, the analytical solution to the system can be calculated exactly assuming the matrix exponential can be calculated.
In Matlab, the matrix exponential is calculate via the [`expm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html) function.
The following code computes the analytical solution and compares it to the numerical one for a short time span:

```
%   Set-up
A    = [-23788605396486326904946699391889i/38685626227668133590597632,23788605396486326904946699391889i/38685626227668133590597632;...
        -2500000+5223289665997855453060886952725538686654593059791i/324518553658426726783156020576256,23788605396486326904946699391889i/38685626227668133590597632];
Eqns = @(t,X) A*X;
X0   = [0;1];

%   Numerical
options = odeset('RelTol',1E-8,'AbsTol',1E-8);
[t,Xabc]=ode45(Eqns,[0 1E-9],X0,options);

%   Analytical
Xana = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(tk) expm(A*tk)*X0,t,'UniformOutput',false)')';

k = 1;
%   Plots
figure(1);
    subplot(3,1,1)
        plot(t,abs(Xana(:,k)),t,abs(Xabc(:,k)),'--');
        title('Magnitude');
    subplot(3,1,2)
        plot(t,real(Xana(:,k)),t,real(Xabc(:,k)),'--');
        title('Real');
        ylabel('Values');
    subplot(3,1,3)
        plot(t,imag(Xana(:,k)),t,imag(Xabc(:,k)),'--');
        title('Imaginary');
        xlabel('Time');
```

The comparison plot is:

[image: Comparison of analytical and numerical solutions]

The output of `ode45` matches the magnitude and real parts of the solution very well, but the imaginary portion is out-of-phase by exactly π.
However, since `ode45`'s error estimator only looks at norms, the phase difference is not noticed which may lead to problems depending on the application.

It will be noted that while the matrix exponential solution is far more costly than `ode45` *for the same number of time vector elements*, the analytical solution will produce the exact solution for any time vector of any density given to it.  So for long time solutions, the matrix exponential can be viewed as an improvement in some sense.

Comment: Thank you @TroyHaskin . Yes, you are correct i am trying to solve the an atomic physics problem numerically to 300 microsecond. The actual system consists of 625 coupled ODE' s but it is difficult to put the lengthy code which i wrote and ask a question i just took 2 equations out and try to solve them where i got the same error message as i got for 625 equations. Since such a big system cann't be solved analytically i have to go for numerical approach only. So i have chosen ODE45. Yes now it is taking lot of time to solve them. Can you suggest me how to make it solve faster ? Thank you again.

Comment: @user3218696 Is the system similar to the one presented, meaning linear with constant coefficients?

Comment: Yes they are linear with constant coefficients just as the above two equations.. but they are complex numbers also in the cofficients.

Comment: @user3218696 I have added to the answer.